# Cloudwatch for billing alarm in daily based using cloudwatch metric

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

May I ask is there any way that I can make a billing alarm for a daily based cost via cloudwatch metric?

I know that billing alarm is in monthly basis. Is there a possiblity that I can create a custom metric to get the daily cost then set a threshold let say if I spend $2 on AWS Lambda service it will trigger and notify via sns.

Thanks! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the AWS Cost Explorer API to programmatically retrieve cost and usage metrics for your account. You can query for aggregated data such as total monthly costs or total daily usage, but you can also query for granular data.

To solve your requirement, you could set up a scheduled CloudWatch Event that triggers a Lambda, which in turn analyzes (and reports on) the [cost and usage data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_GetCostAndUsage.html) from the previous day or get the [cost forecast](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_GetCostForecast.html) for a specified time period in the future.

Here's the [AWS Cost Explorer API Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html).

Comment: Thanks for that! What if I want this on cloudwatch custom metric? Is that possible?